# Probability - Bus stop and coffee shop

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following question.  I can do the previous parts where you are calculating expectation values for your length of walk etc but I am not sure on the below.  Does it have some conditional element eg p(you can fetch a coffee | you have picked the closest route to the bus stop)

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Q) You arrive at a road and all you know is that you are somewhere between two bus stops which are one mile apart.

You also know that there is a coffee stop somewhere between the two bus stops.

If you head to the closer bus stop, what is the chance that you can fetch a coffee on your way?

Original question attached for full context

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcvYO.png

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Your question lacks information for it to be answerable. How long does it take you to go fetch the coffee? Where is the coffee shop located? How fast do you walk?

Comment: Hi Therkel.  Thanks for the reply.  Sorry, I did miss a point in my question.  We are also aware that somewhere between the bus stops, there is a coffee shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $Y$ is the position of the coffeeshop and $X$ is your position, then you will walk past the coffeeshop if and only if $Y \le X \le \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2} \le X \le Y$. Here, $X$ and $Y$ are indepentent random variables, distributed uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks Dominik.  This was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since you don’t know where you are, you assume that your position $X$ is a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable. You can just use the properties of uniform random variables, which makes it a lot easier to solve.

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for the hint.  Yeah, I gathered it was the uniform distribution.  I used that in the previous part of the question where you calculate the pdf of the length of the shortest route and expectation value for how long you walk on this route.  I'm still pulling a bit of a mind blank on this one though.
If A is prob that you can get a coffee, B the prob you have picked the shortest route, then P(a\B) = P(A intersection B)/P(B).  I'm just not sure how to calculate these individually...